# ssh -t -t sudo displays back my password

Tags: ssh, unix, sudo

My problem is about executing sudo over SSH. I have tried various things, but non works.

Here is my script:

```
ssh my-host /bin/bash << EOF
# some commands...

sudo -u my-user -s -- << EOFF
# other commands...
EOFF

EOF
```

Like that, I get

> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

So I tried with option -t for ssh

```
ssh -t my-host /bin/bash << EOF
```

Still get the same message. So I tried with double -t -t:

```
ssh -t -t my-host /bin/bash << EOF
```

Now I get to the password prompt, except I can see my password as I type it and pressing enter has no effect.

Additional constraint: I have limited rights on my-host. I cannot sudo, except to become user my-user.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just `ssh my-user@my-host`?

Comment: Because for some reason this does not work either, although I set up my ssh key and put all the right modes for .ssh and .ssh/authorized_keys. I guess the system admin deactivated it somehow.

Comment: that is probably the weirdest attempt to misuse heredoc I have ever seen. Use the keys. If you can't, use `expect` (a lot questions around here), which gives you much better control of what is going on in your code.

Comment: When you use a here-doc, there's no way for the remote terminal control to affect how you interact locally. The here-doc is read on the client machine before anything is sent to the server.

Comment: Assuming your script changes rarely, you should probably just install it on the remote system and enable your account to run it as root with `NOPASSWD` in that system's `/etc/sudoers`.  That way, you can just `ssh my-host sudo /path/to/that/script` and not have to worry about interactivity at all.